# MySQL INSERT BETWEEN

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create multiple inputs from a PHP file to my database. I came across with MySQL BETWEEN and NOT BETWEEN which I think will help my task a lot with the operations. So far I have successfully manage to make them operate in DELETE and UPDATE functions but not in insert. I tried both SET and VALUES syntax but both complaining about syntax error. Something like INSERT INTO DB (ID,etc) VALUES (BETWEEN min AND max, etc) and also INSERT INTO DB SET ID=BETWEEN min AND MAX , etc. Both come with Syntax error.

Comment: "DB" is your table name?

Comment: That's not what `BETWEEN` means. `a BETWEEN b AND c` is short-hand for `((a >= b) AND (a <= c))`. It's for `WHERE` clauses. You can't use it like that.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT and UPDATE are meant to set specific values for a column.  When you write BETWEEN min and max, you're not giving a specific value.  BETWEEN is meant to find data between certain values.